# Rails controlled test not passing after adding validation for uniquness

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

I had a simple test in my record_controller_test.rb which passed with no issues at first.

```
  test "should create record" do
    assert_difference('Record.count') do
    post records_url, params: { record: { category_id: @record.category_id, user_id: @record.user_id } }
  end
```

I had to make sure each new record created is unique though, so I added the following into the model:

```
validates :user_id, :uniqueness => {:scope => :category_id}
```

Now the test fails. How should I rewrite the test to account for the new uniqueness validation?

Update:
Here is the controller code:

```
 def new
    @record = Record.new
    @users = User.all
  end

  def create
    @record = Record.new(record_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @record.save
        format.html { redirect_to @record, notice: 'Record was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @record }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @record.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

The form:

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :user_id %>
    <%= form.collection_select :user_id, @users, :id, :name %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :category_id %>
    <%= form.collection_select :category_id, @categories, :id, :category %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please provide controller code as it hard to understand what is an issue.
Also if there are any callbacks for the models would be great to see it here.
And where do you assign the `@record` variable?
The issue could be in each of this areas.
I assume test or some callback implicitly created record with this params. So just need to find where

Comment: Are you using database_cleaner or something else to truncate your db between test runs? If not, then you already have the unique record stored and the test will fail because the record already exists.

Comment: I think you have a record with same category and user in your fixtures. So you need to create something different in the test

Comment: Updated the post with the controller and the view. The two validation fields are both picklists. I am not using database_cleaner, but I did try wiping the db entirely then executing the test. Still fails.

Comment: How are you creating the `User` and th `Cagetory` in your test?